# Checking for running .bat files

Tags: batch-file

I need to have a `.bat` file running on a PC all the time, which exports data every 8 hours.

The `.bat` file I would like to build would make hourly checks to see if the other `.bat` file is running, and if not start it.

I know `tasklist` can't find `.bat` files which is why I'm using `WINDOWTITLE` instead.

I am assuming that `ERRORLEVEL` = `1` means the test failed.

I have looked around a lot and best I have come up with is this but it doesn't work.

```
tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Export"
if errorlevel=0 START C:\ExportApps\Export.bat
TIMEOUT /T 3600
GOTO LOOP
```

When it checks for the second time it starts another instance of the `.bat` file.

If I change the `ERRORLEVEL` to `1` I get the following:

> INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.

Comment: Just use the task scheduler, there is absolutely no reason to have a batch file running constantly which only does something three times per day, and even less need to have another batch file running constantly making hourly checks that the other one is still running!

Answer (score 0):

`tasklist` doesn't set errorlevel to 1 when there is no finding. (Ab)use `find` to get a correct errorlevel:

```
tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq Export"   | find /c "cmd.exe"   1>nul  && exit /b
REM code for restarting
```

Schedule it to be run every hour (or consider Compo's advice to schedule your primary batch file, when it actually doesn't *have* to run all the time for some reason).